# Reading Multilingual Data RSS feed Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, rss

I have to read the RSS feed given at

http://www.almanar.com.lb/english/rss.php

So when i am using jquery to parse the xml data like

$.ajax({

```
url: 'http://www.almanar.com.lb/english/rss.php',
dataType: 'xml',
beforeSend: function () {
$('.overlay').fadeIn('fast');
}
```

});

The above is just a snapshot for the code, my code is working fine. 
I am getting issue in the cases when there is multilingual data in some news description like

**In what the Pentagon called a "significant milestone" in the effort to close the prison at Guant&#225namo Bay, Cuba, the military announced Tuesday that the United States had transferred three Chinese detainees to Slovakia**

Here &#225 is creating issue and when i am parsing it as a html i am able to read it but in that case i am not able to read the link tag coming in the rss feed.

So can anybody tell me how can i resolve the issue